# organizing numbers in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have some numbers in list which i want to organize with numpy.Heres my code

```
lst=['99.56','99.76','99.84','100.00','100.00','100.00','100.00','100.00','100.00','99.80','99.43']

lst2=[]

    for i in np.arange(95.0,100.0,0.1):
        x=0
        for j in lst:
            if float(i)+0.1>= float(j) > float(i):
                x=x+1
        lst2.append(x)

lst2=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

I didn't understand why the last item is 0.There are 6 '100.00'.How come it's not 6?.

Thanks

Comment: In what way do you wish to organize them?  Are you trying to place your input into bins?  Can you provide us with the **expected output** of your code?

Comment: Yes im trying to put them into bins.The expected output is simple,the lst2 is correct except the end of it,which should be 6 instead of 0 because there are 6 100.00.Probably im missing something simple but i couldn't find it for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ndarray` generated by `numpy.arange` does generally *not* include the end value:

```
In [15]: np.arange(99.0, 100., 0.1)
Out[15]: array([ 99. ,  99.1,  99.2,  99.3,  99.4,  99.5,  99.6,  99.7,  99.8,  99.9])
```

Note that there is a built-in method `numpy.histogram` to do this for you;

```
In [13]: np.histogram(lst, list(np.arange(95.0,100.2,0.1)))
Out[13]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 2, 0, 6, 0]), array([  95. ,   95.1,   95.2,   95.3,   95.4,   95.5,   95.6,   95.7,
         95.8,   95.9,   96. ,   96.1,   96.2,   96.3,   96.4,   96.5,
         96.6,   96.7,   96.8,   96.9,   97. ,   97.1,   97.2,   97.3,
         97.4,   97.5,   97.6,   97.7,   97.8,   97.9,   98. ,   98.1,
         98.2,   98.3,   98.4,   98.5,   98.6,   98.7,   98.8,   98.9,
         99. ,   99.1,   99.2,   99.3,   99.4,   99.5,   99.6,   99.7,
         99.8,   99.9,  100. ,  100.1,  100.2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking about...do you want to sort `lst`, or make a new list, `lst2` based on `lst`? Clarifying your question would help to get a better answer.

If you are trying to do the first, why not just use an array?

```
testarray = np.array(lst)
testarray.sort() # This will sort from largest to smallest.
```

As to your question about why the last entry in your `lst2` is 0, look at your logic. You ask if the value of `i+0.1` is larger than `j` and `i`. For the last entry, you would have:
    i+1 = 100.0
    j = 99.43
    i = 99.9

`i+0.1` is greater than or equal to `j`, but `j` is NOT greater than `i`. This evaluates to false, thus your value of x remains 0.